# GLIBC_2.14 for slackware 13.37

Tags: tor, slackware, glibc

I am trying to run [tor](https://www.torproject.org/index.html.en) on my slackware machine and when I do I get the error:

> tor: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required for
>   tor)

So I run the command:

`slackpkg upgrade glibc`

Which tells me that there are no packages that match the pattern for upgrade.

So then I run the following command to reinstall glibc:

`slackpkg reinstall glibc`

And when I am prompted by the reinstall screen to choose the packages that I want to reinstall, I notice that `glibc-2.13_64-5_slack13.37.txz` is the latest version of glibc.

Is it possible to either run tor without the latest [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), get glibc_2.14 for slackware 13.37 another way, or some other solution to properly run tor on slackware 13.37?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment a mirror URL that ends in 'slackware64-current', e.g.

> ftp://mirrors.usc.edu/pub/linux/distributions/slackware/slackware64-current/

If you use a mirror that ends in 'slackware64-13.37' you won't see GLIBC 2.14.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Slackware64? If `glibc-2.13_64-5_slack13.37.txz` is the package name, then you are installing the wrong package; search the 64-bits version and try again.

Comment: I am not searching for the package, I am getting it directly from the mirror that you uncomment, inorder to use the slackpkg command. Also I am having a hard time finding the version 2.14 glibc for slackware on the internet. Is there another distro that is close enough to slackware, where I can you that package?